# Submitting id of parent div of button using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, parent

I am trying to submit the ID of the parent DIV that a button is in using AJAX.  This is the markup:

```
<div id="32"><input id="button" type="button" class="before" onclick="add_fav();" /></div>
```

and this is the ajax script in its current state:

```
<script>
function add_fav()
{   
jQuery.ajax({       
      url: 'addfav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'id':jQuery(this).closest("div").attr("id"),is_ajax: 1},
      success: function(html) {
        jQuery('#button').removeClass('before');
        jQuery('#button').addClass('after');
        jQuery('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }, 
      error: function() {
        jQuery('#error').html('<div>Error! Unable to add food item.</div>');
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

This isn't working so the method I am using to pass the id of the DIV is clearly not right.  Perhaps someone could put me straight?

Comment: What is `this` in `jQuery(this).closest(...`?

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be what the problem is.  I was hoping that 'this' would refer to the button that was being clicked.  Obviously not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using an inline click handler pass a reference to the clicked item to your function:

```
onclick="add_fav(this);"
```

Then:

```
function add_fav(btn)
{   
   jQuery.ajax({       
      url: 'addfav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'id':jQuery(btn).closest("div").attr("id"),is_ajax: 1},
      success: function(html) {
        jQuery('#button').removeClass('before');
        jQuery('#button').addClass('after');
        jQuery('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }, 
      error: function() {
        jQuery('#error').html('<div>Error! Unable to add food item.</div>');
      }
    });
}
```

Within the inline attribute `this` does refer to the clicked element, but not within the function you're calling (unless you take steps to make it so with `.call()` or `.apply()`).

However, I'd recommend binding the event handler with jQuery:

```
jQuery("input.before").click(function(){
   jQuery.ajax({       
      url: 'addfav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'id':jQuery(this).closest("div").attr("id"),is_ajax: 1},
      success: function(html) {
        jQuery('#button').removeClass('before');
        jQuery('#button').addClass('after');
        jQuery('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }, 
      error: function() {
        jQuery('#error').html('<div>Error! Unable to add food item.</div>');
      }
    });
});
```

...and then jQuery makes sure `this` is set appropriately, and also you don't need the inline onclick. Put the above in a document.ready handler or in a script block that appears after the button (e.g., at the end of the body).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the element to the function as a parameter so you can use it in the function. `onclick="add_fav(this);"`

```
<script>
function add_fav(element)
{   
jQuery.ajax({       
      url: 'addfav.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'id':jQuery(element).closest("div").attr("id"),is_ajax: 1},
      success: function(html) {
        jQuery('#button').removeClass('before');
        jQuery('#button').addClass('after');
        jQuery('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      }, 
      error: function() {
        jQuery('#error').html('<div>Error! Unable to add food item.</div>');
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

If you still want to use `this` in the function you can use [`function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), `onclick="add_fav.call(this);"` and use `add_fav` how you have it.